# How to delete decimals that have repeating decimals

Tags: matlab, decimal, repeat

I'm working on a code able to work data from star of a public catalogue. I've already got arrays of every single variable that is available:

```
enter code here fid=fopen('000006+2553.txt','r');
i=1;
while 1
tline=fgetl(fid);
if ~ischar(tline), break, end
A{i}=tline;
i=i+1;
end


k=1;
for j=1:1:length(A)
    if length(A{j}) > 50 && length(A{j})<=92
       B{k}=A{j};
       k=k+1;
    end
end

m=1;
    for l=1:1:length(B)
       C=strread(B{l},'%s','delimiter',' ');
       HJD(m)=str2num(C{1});
       MAG_3(m)=str2num(C{2});
       MAG_0(m)=str2num(C{3});
       MAG_1(m)=str2num(C{4});
       MAG_2(m)=str2num(C{5});
       MAG_4(m)=str2num(C{6});
       MER_3(m)=str2num(C{7});
       MER_0(m)=str2num(C{8});
       MER_1(m)=str2num(C{9});
       MER_2(m)=str2num(C{10});
       MER_4(m)=str2num(C{11});
       FRAME(m)=str2num(C{13});
       m=m+1;
   end
```

My problem is, that some of the values in the arrays are repeating decimals, like 29.99999 and 99.99999....etc. Since this numbers are the result of saturation of the sensor, they are wrong data, and must be eliminated. Is there anyway I can tell MATLAB to delete this particular numbers? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: without trying to understand your code, you should have a look at the `unique` function, but it would require that the data is exactly the same in case of saturation. Otherwise use `round`,`ceil` or `floor` in advance

Comment: How about this: eliminate if the following condition satisfies:

`if abs(round(yourNumber)-yourNumber)<delta  %delta is a small no.
     %eliminate the number
end`

Comment: Thank you both, i will try the option of rounding the number see if it works. The option of using "unique" was a good one, but unfortunately these numbers are not always repeated, and since there variable measured is something like an oscilation, there are repeated numbers that actually cant be eliminated. Anyway thanks, ill see if the rounding option works.